# How do I display the formatted content of React Quill ? I can get just the plain text but I want the text with applied CSS to display

Tags: reactjs, quill

I managed to get the text from Quill editor, but I need to pass the text which is formatted with the editor to my other component, not just the plain text. Can anyone please help me? I tried the Quill API and different methods but I either get just the plain text or the HTML in my other component. All examples I have found is showing how to pass the content which is just the plain text and none nothing about the changed and formatted text.

```
 import React from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import ReactQuill, { Quill } from "react-quill";
    import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
    import Display from './Display';
    import "../index.css"



    class Editor extends React.Component {

      constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        console.log(props);
        this.modules = {
                toolbar: [
                  [{ 'font': [] }],
                  [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
                  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
                  [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
                  [{ 'align': [] }],
                  [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
                  ['clean']
                ]
            };

            this.formats = [
                'font',
                'size',
                'bold', 'italic', 'underline',
                'list', 'bullet',
                'align',
                'color', 'background'
          ];

        this.state = { editorHtml: '' ,
          content:'', comments:''
          } 
          this.rteChange = this.rteChange.bind(this);
          this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);


      }

      handleChange = (text) =>{

        this.setState({editorHtml: text})
        this.props.onTextSubmit(text);

      }
        // onChange(content, delta, source, editor,comments) {
        //   const text = editor.getText(content);
        //   this.setState ({ content: text });
        //   console.log(text);
        //   console.log(editor.getContents())
        //   const con = editor.getContents();
        //   //const test = editor.setContents(delta);
        //   //this.setState({comments: con})
        //   // console.log(editor.getFormat());  
        // }

        onChange(html) {
          this.setState ({ content: html });
            console.log(html)
          }

        on= ('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
          if (source == 'api') {
            console.log(delta);
          // } else if (source == 'user') {
          //   console.log("A user action triggered this change.");
          //}
        }});

      render () {
        return (
          <div>

            <ReactQuill 
              ref='editor'
              theme="snow"  modules={this.modules}
              formats={this.formats} 
              test={this.test}
              onChangeSelection={this.onChangeSelection}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              //value={this.state.comments || ''}
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              test2={this.test2}

             />
      {/* <div  ><input type="text" name="name"  onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
                value={this.state.editorHtml}/>{this.state.comments} </div> */}

               <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.content}}></div>
           </div>

         )
      }

    }


    export default Editor;
```

Comment: I did not quite understand your question. It seems to me that you want to get Quill content. But how do you want this content? Do you want it formatted, with colors, fonts, headers, images, videos and etc, or do you just want any text present? Anyway, maybe [this](https://github.com/loagit/Quill-Examples-and-FAQ#quill-faq) can help you. See item 023.

Comment: Hi Loa, when I change the colour of the text in my editor I get this change in my other component but if I change the Size or Font of the text in the editor nothing gets updated in the other component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the editor in view mode (read only) and set its default value with html content you want to display.